# Float an element to the right within containing parent with variable width in IE<=7

Tags: html, css

I have a container-div with no set width, that contains a table of variable width, and also a button below the table. I'd like this button to float on the right so that its right edge lines up with the right edge of the table.
Doing something like the following seems to work fine in all browsers but IE<=7. How is this done correctly?

```
<head>
    <style>
#tableContainer {
    float: left;
}
#btn {
  float: right;
}

    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="tableContainer">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button id="btn">buttontext</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's an illustration of what I want:

```
__________________
|                |
|       table    |
|________________|
             |btn|
             ‾‾‾‾‾
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, one solution I finally worked out is the following:

```
<head>
    <style>
#tableContainer {
    float: left;
}
#btncontainer {
  text-align: right;
}

    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="tableContainer">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                    <td>a b c</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    <div id="btncontainer">
                <button>buttontext</button>
    </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What we did here is create a button-container and set "text-align:right" on it. Alternatively we could skip the btn-container and put text-align in the table-container instead, assuming there's no other elements that need to be on the left (This wont affect how the table is positioned as long as it's wider than the button in my case.

To me it does feel really illogical using text-align to align a button though. Any comments on that?

Answer (score 0):

can you take the button out of the div? that should solve your problem.

else, add `float:left` on `#tableContainer table` (not recommended)

You could also wrap your table into another div, and float that div to the left

also, you have to move the button before the table

Comment: Not sure you got me right. But I've added an illustration to the question so that you can see what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you mean..

```
    #tableContainer {
        float:left;
    }
    #btn {
        position:relative;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        float:right;
    }
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLyMT/2/)**

**or else**

```
    #tableContainer {
        float:left;
        display: inline;
    }
    #btn {
        float:right;
        display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: No, sorry. That's not it. Seems I didn't make myself clear. I've added an illustration of what I want to the original question.

Comment: @Clox check my updated post. I can't test in IE7, also check using `display:inline` in combination with `float` properties.

Comment: I appreciate your help.
Adding display:inline to the elements like that didn't make any difference though =/ The button keeps ending up at the far right of the screen in IE7. I thought this would be dead simple and I was just missing something obvious. Still can't seem to get it working properly =/